# How can I safely remove my laptop's entire lid?

Tags: laptop-repair, laptop-display

Short version: son uses laptop. Laptop is mysteriously broken.

Something got badly crushed in the lid. After replacing both the LCD and inverter card I'm ready to declare the display defunct.

Since the VGA out still works, I plan to salvage the laptop by using it to replace my ailing Linux server. That would work much better (and be much cooler) if I permanently removed the entire lid, leaving me with a cute, flat, keyboard-equipped server.

The surgical details for my specific laptop (Toshiba U305) are probably too much to ask, but are there general things I should be careful about with this kind of procedure? Any cables I should be careful not to leave dangling once the lid is gone? Is there a good DIY/mod guide for this kind of project? Googling likely keywords is finding tons of repair guides, not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, that the wifi aerials are attached to the lid. Also you should be very, very careful while opening the body. Always remember,most parts are reachable without removing the entire body. Maybe you can find some building plans with Google. I was able to find some for my HP compaq nx6325 some years ago.

Comment: Good point about the wifi, though I suspect he won't be using it on a server system anyway, except maybe as a hotspot.

Comment: Thanks Diskilla, +1 on the wifi. I agree Joel, I probably won't need the wifi on a server... but still, it's an issue I want to bear in mind since I'd like to keep the wifi option open just in case.

Answer (score 2):

Try searching for [toshiba u305 tear down](http://www.google.com/search?q=toshiba+u305+tear+down).  You can often find detailed instructions or even a video of the process.

Comment: +1 Thanks Chris, I was missing the keyphrase "tear down". I'll look through those results.